# Element is not getting selected in Selenium Python Firefox Web Scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, firefox

I have problem with element selection checkbox with one of the list item in below code snippet.

I'm able to select 1st 2nd & 4th Element in below code, however I'm not able to select 3rd element.

When I give only Taj Hotels, Oberoi Hotels and Sheraton India. All three are getting checked by python selenium web scrapping. When I add Windsor Hotels to list, it's not selecting it script shows error like below.

**selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view**

Note: whenever an item is selected it's class name is getting is changed to "list-item star ng-star-inserted active"

I'm running this using windows 10, Pycharm IDE.

selenium==3.7.0
cryptography=3.1.1
pandas

Python Script:

```
txt_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text() = "' + element_to_be selected + '"]')
txt_button.click()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
<fd-order-supplier-list _ngcontent-ydw-c199="">
    <div class="block-list block-list-selectable block-list-sm">
        <div class="the-list">
            <fd-order-supplier-list-item class="list-item star ng-star-inserted active" _nghost-ydw-c198="">
                <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="list-item-inner">
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-logo placeholder"><!---->
                        <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="logo-placeholder-inner ng-star-inserted">H</div><!----></div>
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-name" style="">Taj Hotels</div>
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-btn"><a _ngcontent-ydw-c198=""
                                                                    class="btn btn-outline-default btn-xs">Add</a></div>
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-check ng-star-inserted">
                        <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-checkbox"><span _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="icon">check</span>
                        </div>
                    </div><!----><a _ngcontent-ydw-c198=""
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-text item-info-link ng-star-inserted"><span
                        _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="icon">visibility</span></a><!---->
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-upper-text">IN</div>
                </div>
            </fd-order-supplier-list-item>
            <fd-order-supplier-list-item class="list-item star ng-star-inserted active" _nghost-ydw-c198="">
                <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="list-item-inner">
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-logo placeholder"><!---->
                        <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="logo-placeholder-inner ng-star-inserted">I</div><!----></div>
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-name" style="">Oberoi Hotels</div>
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-btn"><a _ngcontent-ydw-c198=""
                                                                    class="btn btn-outline-default btn-xs">Add</a></div>
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-check ng-star-inserted">
                        <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-checkbox"><span _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="icon">check</span>
                        </div>
                    </div><!----><a _ngcontent-ydw-c198=""
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-text item-info-link ng-star-inserted"><span
                        _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="icon">visibility</span></a><!---->
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-upper-text">IN</div>
                </div>
            </fd-order-supplier-list-item>
            <fd-order-supplier-list-item class="list-item star ng-star-inserted" _nghost-ydw-c198="">
                <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="list-item-inner">

                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-name">Windsor Hotels</div>
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-btn"><a _ngcontent-ydw-c198=""
                                                                    class="btn btn-outline-default btn-xs">Add</a></div>
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-check ng-star-inserted">
                        <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-checkbox"><span _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="icon">check</span>
                        </div>
                    </div><!----><a _ngcontent-ydw-c198=""
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-text item-info-link ng-star-inserted"><span
                        _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="icon">visibility</span></a><!---->
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-upper-text">IN</div>
                </div>
            </fd-order-supplier-list-item>
            <fd-order-supplier-list-item class="list-item star ng-star-inserted" _nghost-ydw-c198="">
                <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="list-item-inner">

                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-name">Sheraton India</div>
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-btn"><a _ngcontent-ydw-c198=""
                                                                    class="btn btn-outline-default btn-xs">Add</a></div>
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-check ng-star-inserted">
                        <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-checkbox"><span _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="icon">check</span>
                        </div>
                    </div><!----><a _ngcontent-ydw-c198=""
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-text item-info-link ng-star-inserted"><span
                        _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="icon">visibility</span></a><!---->
                    <div _ngcontent-ydw-c198="" class="item-upper-text">IN</div>
                </div>
            </fd-order-supplier-list-item>
        </div>
</fd-order-supplier-list>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Windsor Hotels instead of manor?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
txt_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text() = "' + element_to_be selected + '"]')
```

you can get more canonical adding the *tag_name* and the *class* attribute as follows:

```
txt_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item-name' and text()='" + element_to_be selected + "']")
```

precisely:

```
txt_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item-name' and text()='" + element_to_be selected + "']")
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

Ideally to invoke click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item-name' and text()='" + element_to_be selected + "']"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```